# turn array to vars?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$controller->$method($this->params);
```

ok the problem is that my `$this->params` is **an array**, is there something in php that can we do so it will be like

```
$controller->$method($params1,$params2,$untilllastparams); ?
```

thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for call_user_func_array().  In your example this would look like:

```
call_user_func_array(array($controller, $method), $this->params);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Answer (score 0):

I assume that controller is some library class and you are looking for a different interface. One solution is to define a wrapper function:

```
function my_wrapper(ControllerClass &$controller, &$params1, &$params2, &$untilllastparams) {
  // create array from parameters
  $controller->$method($param_array);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) and "implode" functions (http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). Basically implode your array as a comma delimited string (this will represent your method parameters) and then build a string like so,

```
$implodedString = implode(",", $this->params);
eval("$controller->$method($implodedString);")
```

It's likely not the most ideal solution, and I don't have any way to test it right now, but give it a go.

Comment: I think Adam Hupp's got the answer for ya.